# Как исправить контакт с объектом в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, move

Есть 2d персонаж, которому я задал передвижение через rigidbody2d, ещё использовал boxcollider2d. При прыжке, когда ты находишься с права/лева от объекта  на который ты хочешь запрыгнуть впритык, то персонаж начинает зависать в объекте или подлетать в несколько раз выше нормы, как это исправить?

Comment: Youtube: CharacterController

Comment: @Yaroslav Он же не работает в 2d, разве нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать в папке PhysicsMaterial2d и в нем friction поставить на 0. В бокс коллайдер добавить наш материал

Comment: Мне вообще не помогло, пробовал повесить на boxcollider, rigidbody.

Comment: На объект с которым взаимодействуете тоже повесьте, если еще не решили проблему

Comment: Я уже пробовал вчера, я знаю ещё один способ, попробую его.